# Anyone knows what this $\phi_0$ function is?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

As shown below, I don't know what the highlighted "$\phi_0$" stands for. I think this is related to Gamma function.

I can recognize another function $\psi_0$ (the last equation in the screen shot) is digamma function.

> [image]

It looks like the proof just skips this. The proof just approximates $(a+b)_N/(b)_N$, and plug it back in. The original file is here. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1007.0296.pdf, page 20 (statement) and 41 (proof).

> [image]

Comment: Could it be just a typo?

Comment: After looking up the usage of the symbol $\phi$, I could only find one that had a subscript that was not a random variable, the [cyclotomic polynomial functions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial).

Comment: Some people use $\phi (x)$ as the  standard normal distributions pdf with variable x. since it is mentioned in a section about convergence that might be related although I do not see how the statement is arrived in that case